# compare 2 arrays and get key of one with value of the other one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in React, I have 2 arrays:

```
const arr1 = [
{id: 1, name: 'Hello'}
{id: 2, name: 'Dear'}
{id: 3, name: 'World'}
]

const arr2 = ['Hello', 'Dear']
```

I would like the arr2 values to be the id of the arr1 and end up with this:

```
const arr2 = [1, 2]
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `arr2` and find the item with the same name in `arr1`. Then take the id of that item.

```js
const arr1 = [
{id: 1, name: 'Hello'},
{id: 2, name: 'Dear'},
{id: 3, name: 'World'}
]

let arr2 = ['Hello', 'Dear']

let nameToId = arr1.reduce((result, item) => ({ ...result, [item.name]: item.id}), {}); 


arr2 = arr2.map((name) => nameToId[name]);

console.log(arr2);
```